# Adding advertising in my app

Tags: android

I just done my first app and I want to add some advertising to my app, Can I add it now or I have to wait for a certain number of downloads?

And how can receive the funds if there was any?

Comment: Please consider reading the documentation. It's all answered there.

Comment: refer this link: https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/ads.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add banners in your application read this link https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals

more http://developer.android.com/training/monetization/ads-and-ux.html / https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/ads.html

Do some google search to find more.

Anyway, it's not recommended to add banners after the application is released, the user tend to feel the change more and could stop using your app, but if you app already contains some non-intrusive ads they don't notice anything.

Anyway, if they don't use your application you don't make anything

Answer (score 1):

See this here for info: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/

You don't need a certain number of downloads, I believe, but with <1K downloads, you probably will make only pennies.

Answer (score 1):

Google AdMob require a valid Content for your add view. You need to have a complete source code of your work plus you need to have some content in your page. After you sign up to the service, they consider if your page is valid and if your page is accepted, you can use the view.